# Correct way to do oversampling, gridsearch and cross validation together?

Tags: scikit-learn, cross-validation, gridsearchcv

For a given dataset with input features `X_all` and prediction labels `y_all` for a binary classification problem, I want to oversample my data using SMOTE, find best parameters for my learning algorithm using `GridSearchCV` and then observe the results by running a `10 fold cross validation.` What is the best way to do this?

I understood that it is bad to oversample the entire data-set beforehand and then do cross validation on it because of the risk of data leakage. What I am not sure is should I apply `GridSearch` only on a part of the dataset or the entire dataset since it also has an option to use `cross-validation`. If I use cross-validation during GridSearch on the entire dataset, is that it - how do I achieve/observe the results after 10 fold cv?

My code so far:

```
pipe = Pipeline([('resample', SMOTE(sampling_strategy=1)),
    ('model', KNeighborsClassifier())])

cv = StratifiedKFold(n_splits=10)

params = [{'model__n_neighbors':[1,3,5,15,25,45],
          'model__weights':['uniform','distance'],
          'model__leaf_size': [3,5,7,9,15,25]}]
grid_search = GridSearchCV(
    estimator=pipe, param_grid=params, cv=cv, refit=True
)
grid_search.fit(X_all, y_all)
grid_search.best_params_
```

So what I am asking is:

1. I used `X_all,y_all` during grid_search, is that correct or should I do a hold-out before hand like a 70/30 split and do the grid search only on the training half?
2. Can I see evaluation metrics like `accuracy, f1`? If yes, how?

Comment: i have this same issue and unfortunately i can see you never got an answer.